# Custom Java method that can take a target as parameter

Tags: java

I am an intermediate Java programmer, and very often use methods that are able to take a target as a parameter. Methods such as:

```
String.substring();
String.indexOf();
```

So I was wondering, how do I create a method that can take a target `String`, etc.?

Comment: You add it as an argument to your methods...

Comment: Yes.  Neil is right.  You're clearly not an intermediate programmer, sorry.

Define your method signature to accept your parameter.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: Your question is **extremely** unclear.

Comment: What do you mean "takes target as a parameter"? You mean modifies in place?

Comment: Please explain more if you can, like what do you mean by "target"

Comment: If you need to pass action as a parameter look at [Command pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-command).

Comment: InfernalRapture - I'm sorry, I had assumed you knew what I meant by "target" given that it is a widely used term for (layman's terms) "the thing before the method." And of course I know that I can use it as a parameter, and it was not what I was asking. I don't recall seeing "parameter" anywhere in the question. Besides, I didn't want to use a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`String.substring();` and `String.indexOf();` are examples of instance methods of the `String` class.  They are methods that act on objects of that class.

`String` is a `final` class in `Java`, and as such it can not be extended to add your own methods to it.  You'll have to create your own class.

Perhaps, for example:

```
public class MyString {

    private String s;

    public new(String newValue) {
        s = newValue;
    }

    public someNewMethod() {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Now, on object of your `MyString` class, you can do this...

```
MyString ms = new MyString("Hello World.");

ms.someNewMethod();
```

Comment: Thank you sir / ma'am. This is exactly what I was asking for. Would have asked my compsci teacher but I didn't want to wait until tomorrow. Thanks.